# Undefined index error when trying to find image size

Tags: php, image

I want to find an uploaded image size using `getimagesize` and I got this error:

> Undefined index: `image` in `C:\wamp\www\cbir\process.php` on line 47.

Lines of code that give the error:

```
$info = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

the whole code:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">
<input name="upload" type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload binary file">
</form>
<?php

$dbdatabase = "cbir";
$config_carname = "Content Based Image Retrieval";
$config_author = "Copyright &copy; 2013 shahd & arwa . All Rights Reserved.<br>      Designed by shahd & arwa";
$config_basedir = "http://localhost/cbir/";
$SCRIPT_NAME="process.php"; 

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
  //get file information --step1
  $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
  $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

  //get file content -- step1
  $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $content = fread($fp, $fileSize);
  $content = addslashes($content);
  fclose($fp);

  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
  mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $link)or die("<b>Unable to specified database</b>");


  $reds = array_fill(0, 256, 0);
  $blues = array_fill(0, 256, 0);
  $greens = array_fill(0, 256, 0);

  $info = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

  $width = $info[0];
  $height = $info[1];
  $totalpixels = $width * $height;

  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
  if ($img) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $height; $i++) {
      for ($j = 0; $j < $width; $j++) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $j, $i);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

        if (!isset($reds[$r])) {
          $reds[$r] = 0;
        }
        if (!isset($greens[$r])) {
          $greens[$r] = 0;
        }
        if (!isset($blues[$r])) {
          $blues[$r] = 0;
        }

        // Add counts to our histogram arrays for each color.

        $reds[$r]++;
        $greens[$g]++;
        $blues[$b]++;
      }
    }

    $red_count=count($reds);
    $blue_count=count($blues);
    $green_count=count($greens);        }

    //insert into database --step3 
    $query = "INSERT INTO cbir (image, red_count,blue_count,green_count) VALUES    ('$content','$red_count','$blue_count','$green_count')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

    //return insert information to client
    $id= mysql_insert_id();
    echo "File<b> $fileName</b> uploaded as id= $id<br>";
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with duplicate marked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` tag?

**EDIT** :

What is supposed to be in `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`?

Shouldn't it be the same than `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`?

You don't have any `name="image"` field in your HTML code.

Since you created a `$tmpName` variable, you should reuse it instead of recalling `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` each time.

Comment: Yes I did so . Would you like to see the whole code ?

Comment: Of course yes please paste it in your question.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your HTML Code.

Comment: I tried every thing as a parameter to getimagesize. but still have an error so the las parameter i used was $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']

Comment: And you just try random keywords until it works?

Comment: No I tried solutions from the internet. Thank I replaced $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] with $tmpName and it worked

Comment: I have a new problem the $red_count, $blue_count and $green_count are all have the same value which is 256

Comment: `$red_count = count($reds)` count the size of the array. Since you `array_filled` `$reds` array with 256 `0`, it's size is indeed 256. What would you want in `$red_count`?

Comment: Do you have an idea about how to count array elements? I cant replace array_filled with array() because it keep gives me errors

Comment: Your histogram algorithm seems ok. But what are you trying to count as `$red_counts`? What do you want to insert into your database?

Comment: I want to  retrieve similar images. The user will upload an image and the count of r, g and b will be extracted to compare it with stored  r, g and b for each image in database. the images with the smallest diference will be displayed.

Comment: Well, maybe you don't want to `count($reds)` then, but to `array_sum($reds)`. It will be more relevant to compare red, blue and green sum values.